# Set docker-compose hostname for services with replicas

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I have a simple docker-compose setup with 2 replicas, and each container needs to have a unique hostname. Is it possible to achieve this?

```
services:
  rmq-consumer:
    deploy:
      replicas: 2
    hostname: some-dynamic-value
```

It would be ideal if `hostname` could reference the container name, which docker-compose dynamically generates.

Comment: Can you share why they need to have different hostnames? What are you using the hostname for?

Comment: @sloppypasta yes, we report logs/ metrics with the hostname info, so it's helpful to understand which host such info is coming from